# Solana SPL-22 token fee not claimable

Tags: spl-token, token-2022, fees, authority, fee

I made a Solana spl-2022 memecoin on Dexlab with a 4.9% fee for marketing. Some transactions are made and a withheld amount is visible on the blockchain (solscan). When I look at Dexlab's claim fee tab it shows "no claimable fees". On Phantom when I click my token there is no such option. Also Solflare doesn't even show my token even it's 2 weeks old and has launched days ago. Everytime my wallet that has the withdraw authority. I searched the internet, but almost nothing about spl-22. ChatGPT has also no answer. How do I claim the fee? TA/CA 73NvJWT7RbunzNjXyPHLigGTPUkKWequykjVUc2u3ewJ

Answer (score 0):

Using the `spl-token` CLI, you can simply run:

```
$ spl-token withdraw-withheld-tokens \
 --withdraw-withheld-authority <KEYPAIR_FOR_ATVQAW91oDJCrLQAMvyGzhYzrTrkZidiyW7PcLUGbuB9>
 73NvJWT7RbunzNjXyPHLigGTPUkKWequykjVUc2u3ewJ <DESTINATION_ACCOUNT>
```

This will withdraw from the mint, but you can specify any account with the CLI as well.

More information on using the CLI with transfer fees at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees